# Stretching figure size in a double-y plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure

I'm trying to learn how I can stretch the width of my plot both when showing (`plt.show()`) it and saving (`plt.savefig`) it.

More precisely, the plot has two y-axes that I have written as follows:

```
fig , ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.plot(x,y)
ax2.plot(x,y2)
plt.show()
```

Now the question is, how can I specify the size of the plot, e.g., how do we stretch the width/height? 
When using `plt.show()` and the plot appears, I can manually take one corner and resize the box however desired, but that manually customised size will not be the saved one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the figure size ratio with `figsize=(width, height)`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1, 2, 3]           # dummy data
y = [4, 5, 6]
y2 = [16, 25, 36]

fig , ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 2))   # <-- aspect wider than high
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.plot(x,y)
ax2.plot(x,y2)
plt.show()
```

Comment: excellent! In order to have do without unit specification (inch, cm...), is there a way to simply multiply the current width by a number, say 4? In other words, given the default figsize values, we just want to scale them up or down by a certain factor.

Comment: hum, not sure; the ratio is something like 1.7ish to 1, maybe you can work with a multiple of that?